# why is this looping function so slow compared to map?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I looked at maps source code which basically keeps creating lazy sequences.  I would think that iterating over a collection and adding to a transient vector would be faster, but clearly it isn't.  What don't I understand about clojures performance behavior?

```
;=> (time (do-with / (range 1 1000) (range 1 1000)))
;"Elapsed time: 23.1808 msecs"
;
; vs
;=> (time (doall (map #(/ %1 %2) (range 1 1000) (range 1 1000))))
;"Elapsed time: 2.604174 msecs"
(defn do-with
  [fn coll1 coll2]
  (let [end (count coll1)]
    (loop [i   0
           res (transient [])]
        (if
          (= i end)
            (persistent! res)
            (let [x (nth coll1 i)
                  y (nth coll2 i)
                  r (fn x y)]
              (recur (inc i) (conj! res r))) 
                  ))))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order of conjectured impact on relative results:

1. Your `do-with` function uses `nth` to access the individual items in the input collections. `nth` operates in linear time on ranges, making `do-with` quadratic. Needless to say, this will kill performance on large collections.
2. `range` produces chunked seqs and `map` handles those extremely efficiently. (Essentially it produces chunks of up to 32 elements -- here it will in fact be exactly 32 -- by running a tight loop over the internal array of each input chunk in turn, placing results in internal arrays of output chunks.)
3. Benchmarking with `time` doesn't give you steady state performance. (Which is why one should really use a proper benchmarking library; in the case of Clojure, [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) is the standard solution.)

Incidentally, `(map #(/ %1 %2) xs ys)` can simply be written as `(map / xs ys)`.

*Update:*

I've benchmarked the `map` version, the original `do-with` and a new `do-with` version with Criterium, using `(range 1 1000)` as both inputs in each case (as in the question text), obtaining the following mean execution times:

```
;;; (range 1 1000)
new do-with           170.383334 µs
(doall (map ...))     230.756753 µs
original do-with       15.624444 ms
```

Additionally, I've repeated the benchmark using a vector stored in a Var as input rather than ranges (that is, with `(def r (vec (range 1 1000)))` at the start and using `r` as both collection arguments in each benchmark). Unsurprisingly, the original `do-with` came in first -- `nth` is very fast on vectors (plus using `nth` with a vector avoids all the intermediate allocations involved in seq traversal).

```
;;; (vec (range 1 1000))
original do-with       73.975419 µs
new do-with            87.399952 µs
(doall (map ...))     153.493128 µs
```

Here's the new `do-with` with linear time complexity:

```
(defn do-with [f xs ys]
  (loop [xs  (seq xs)
         ys  (seq ys)
         ret (transient [])]
    (if (and xs ys)
      (recur (next xs)
             (next ys)
             (conj! ret (f (first xs) (first ys))))
      (persistent! ret))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and well rounded response.  Looks like I need to be more aware of what type of operation I'm doing on what type of data structure.